# how to revert commit which is pushed to github reposiroty completely

Tags: github

I have already reverted my changes with `git revert <commit hash>`. But next time when I push code it shows one commit extra which says `revert <reverted commit name>`and my reverted commit stays there. But what should I do to completely removed particular commit so that it is not shown in `commit list` in github repository.

Comment: A "revert commit" is just a simple commit, undoing whatever has changed in "<commit hash>". So all is fine, just push it ;-)
Changing a remote's HEAD can be dangerous if you're working with others.

Comment: Generally speaking you shouldn't try to do that. You've pushed the commit to remote, so other people might have it. Force pushing to erase it entirely rewrites the history of the repository. You should only do it if you, say, committed a password by accident.

Comment: ok,so even if commit is wrongly done, it is good practice to revert it and let github manage everythinh

Answer (score 0):

Run `git reset --hard HEAD~1` to remove the last commit and run then `git push -f` to remove it from Github

Comment: I know, but he asks about Github